# Does the Macho Brace reduce speed?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I don't have some of the Power Items and so I use the Macho Brace instead, but I think the Macho Brace DOES reduce speed growth. When I was EV training my Deoxys, it was at level 99 and the speed stat was at around 400 but after the EV training was complete, the stat became 356.

So does the Macho Brace reduce speed?

Comment: Are you sure you checked the stat outside of battle in both occasions?

Answer (score 4):

Macho brace does not reduce the speed EV, it reduces the speed stat only **in battle** while it's worn by the pokemon.
It's possible that you changed the [form of Deoxys](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Form_differences#Deoxys), thus changing the stats.